# nothing in /boot folder? Replacing Kernels

Tags: linux

I am using Kali linux on my raspberry pi and I am trying to replace the kernal in /boot

I have a new kernel and I thought it would be just getting the old kernel image and calling that kernel.old then replacing it with the new one. But there doesn't seem to be anything in the /boot directory.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not the way to do it. A kernel image comes in .deb package (because Kali is based on Debian), which is richer than just a bunch of files. It is made of two compressed *ar* archives, one for the files, the other for the installation scripts. The installation scripts are interpreted by the Debian package manager, dpkg, in such a way as to make the whole process simple, and of relieving the user of the need for exactly the knowledge you are seeking (where does ... go?).

Normally, alternative kernel images for pcs are easy to locate on the Web: all sorts of keen developers, for instance, produce Debian packages from the newest relases of the Linux kernel. A Google search will easily persuade you of this.

But your case if different because of the architecture of the Raspberry, an ARM pc. You must make sure you find a Debian package suitable for your architecture. Once you have, you install it by means of

```
 sudo dpkg -i my_new_kernel_image.deb
```

Anything else is much more painful.